# Would Apple EarPods work on my Android phone?

Tags: headphones

Apple just launched the iPhone 5; together with that they landed new earphones they call 'EarPods'. I have an HTC Desire HD Android-based phone. It has a 3,5mm jack just as the iPhone. Would the earphones and microphone of the EarPods work on my phone as well? Having good quality earbuds that stick in my ear sounds attractive to me.

I do not care about the controls per se, and I'm pretty sure the sound will also work, but I'm not sure about the microphone. Also, how much of the improved sound and noise reduction is implemented in the software?

Comment: Doubt it would work as that is a proprietary connector, and also, the ground and volt is reversed on the apple connector (don't ask me why!)

Comment: The mic works only if I hold the volume up remote button on my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact. Volume up and down doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly because they use the 3.5mm standard they will transmit sound to Android just as you would expect on the iPhone. All the controls work fine with the exception of the volume up and down. The microphone works currently on Android as well.

Source:
http://www.androidcentral.com/earpods-ear-holes-android

Answer (score 5):

There are four things in Apple EarPod

1. Speakers
2. Microphone
3. Play/Pause Button
4. Volume Up/Down Buttons

### for speaker and microphone

Apple EarPod supports [Universal Head-Phone config](http://pinoutsguide.com/HeadsetsHeadphones/blackberry_9700_headset_pinout.shtml).

Should work with: HTC, Samsung, LG, Most low-brand phones, some Motorola and some Sony, Audio Players.

Microphone and even speaker will work sometimes, but not well, with: Nokia, Most Sony,  Most Motorola.

### for play/pause button

This works for most headsets.

### for Volume Up/Down buttons

This is very, very specific and you'll have to do some research on sites like [pinouts.ru](http://www.pinouts.ru/). People on the Apple store say volume button works well with HTC Wildfire, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think the link to www.pinout.ru is not the correct one.

Comment: Any other than pinout.ru ?

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the comment by @t0mm13b .

I've tried EarPod with couple of Samsung android phones. The **sound works fine** as expected. But the **mic doesn't work** and only gives a constant noise when tried to record audio. Also **play, pause, vol. up, vol. down controls are not working** with android phones.

If you need only its amazing sound quality (for $29), go for it.

The speakers work in correct volume when the impedance matches with the device out. Most phones are having ~32 ohms output impedance.

## Technical specifications:

```
Frequency Response: 5 Hz - 21 kHz
Sensitivity: 109 dB/mW
Impedance: 23 ohms
```

---

### #**[`How to convert Iphone 3.5mm pin to standartd Samsung/Nokia 3.5mm pin?`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68699/convert-iphone-3-5mm-pin-to-standartd-samsung-android-3-5mm-pin)**#

Update: Apple EarPods' mic works fine in recent android phones.