# My android earphone socket doesn't work

Tags: earphone

When i plug my apple earphones into my phone it only plays on speaker. But when i put them into other devices sound comes out. I checked my phones socket to see if anything was maybe stuck in there, looked in my settings, but there was nothing connected to either. I know my ear phones work, but i don't know what else could be wrong. Please help?

Comment: Do other earphones work?

Comment: FYI: [Would Apple EarPods work on my Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29460)

Comment: I don't know, I didn't try other head phones yet, but Yes they should work.

Comment: Well, that's basic troubleshooting. All the advice in the world won't help it's your headphone jack that's faulty.

Comment: Are you running a custom ROM? Did it used to work?

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of your question, it sounds like your earphone jack is faulty and isn't recognising that earphones are connected.

You would have to send your device for repair.