# How do I enable all the functions of an Apple EarPods?

Tags: headphones

Is there any way to make ALL the functions of an Apple EarPods work? The volume up/down won't work.

Comment: what device are you using this on?

Answer (score 0):

An older question, [Would Apple EarPods work on my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29460/would-apple-earpods-work-on-my-android-phone), says the EarPods do not work for Android phones.

However, a question on Apple's site, [Will the EarPods work with other smartphones and audio devices?](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MD827LL/A/will-the-earpods-work-with-other-smartphones-and-audio-devices/QAJD797YC9C97T4UA?page=0&so=newest), says it works on some Android phones, especially on newer ones.

In Google Play, there is [RemoteControl for Earphones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.chobirich.tools.mediabutton&hl=en), which might be useful, but I can't say for sure. *I don't have an EarPod.*